# Как скрыть не влезающие пункты меню в кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Подскажите как сделать так, что бы при ресайзе окна, элементы не влезающие в меню скрывались под кнопку, написал вот такое подобие плагина [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Greyson/cgua5zn6/), вроде работает (уменьшить окно + обновить), однако ни как не могу заставить работать это при `$(window).resize();`.

Comment: Почему не использовать CSS3? У `bootstrap` есть такие фишки, которые подгоняют под размер экрана верстку. Особенно много реализаций у меню как у вас

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вы тестили свой код на сужение экрана?
Надо было сделать подобное, ну немного другая структура. Брал на основе вашего кода.
Но чтоб увидеть на разной ширине, то приходится обновлять страничку

Answer (score 8):

```js
function responseMenu(){
 $('ul.dropdown-menu li.item').appendTo('ul.menu');
 var items = $('ul.menu li.item');
 var max_width = $('ul.menu').width() - $('ul.menu li.dd_menu').outerWidth();
 var width = 0;
 var hide_from = 0;

 items.css({'width':'auto'});

 items.each(function(index){
  if (width + $(this).outerWidth() > max_width)
  {
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   hide_from = index;
   width += $(this).outerWidth();
  }
 });
 if (hide_from < items.length - 1) {
  items.eq(hide_from).nextAll('li.item').appendTo('ul.dropdown-menu');
  items.css({'width':(max_width / (hide_from + 1)) + 'px'});
  $('ul.menu li.dd_menu').show();
 }
 else
 {
  $('ul.menu li.dd_menu').hide();
 }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.top_menu').on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
 });

 $(window).on('resize', function(){
  responseMenu();
 }).trigger('resize');

});
```

```css
ul.menu {padding:0; margin:0;}
ul.menu li {list-style-type:none; display:block; float:left; padding:5px 0; text-align:center; white-space:nowrap;}
ul.menu li.dd_menu {float:right; position:relative; display:none;}
ul.menu ul.dropdown-menu {display:none; position:absolute; top:35px; right:10px; padding:5px; border:#CCC 1px solid; border-radius:5px; z-index:2;}
ul.menu ul.dropdown-menu li {float:none;}
ul.menu a {color: #0b4da2; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top_menu">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li class="dd_menu">
   <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button">+</button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #1</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #2</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #3</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #4</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #5</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #6</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #7</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #8</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #9</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #10</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #11</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #12</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #13</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #14</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><span>Menu item #15</span></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Сенкью вери мач!

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь не правильно понял задачу, но кажется все можно решить с помощью css, добавьте медиа запрос @media (max-width: 000px){} (c нужной шириной) и задайте правило, в котором все отличненько спрячется туда, куда вам нужно.

Comment: Элементы будут меняться, соответственно их ширина тоже, нужно какое-то универсальное решение.

Comment: @Johnny ты читал комментарий мой к своему вопросу? Посмотри что такое `bootstrap`. Там все достаточно просто.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, да, читал, я знаю что такое bootstrap, там нет того что мне нужно (если намекаете на что-то конкретное - скажите, может я не прав).